# Div moves while page is loading

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I'm stuck with a div that is in one position while the page loads, and in another position as the page finishes loading.  I've spent nearly all afternoon on this one little thing, and cannot seem to grasp why this is happening.

I am using wordpress, so there are plenty of different conditional tags for different templates but I can't see the problem in the template files.  The div that seems to be giving me the hard time is the container.  I changed the background color of the container on the template that I'm stuck on, so I can see what its doing while the page loads, and it looks to me like once the page is loads 45px of either margin-top or padding-top are being applied to the container.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I've gone through conditional tags, and my style sheets and I just don't get why its behaving the way it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taken me a couple of page refreshes but I think I can see your problem:

There is this particular DIV: class="entry-image-container" that is loaded into the page despite not being required and is causing your drop down as this element seems to be loading via Opacity in the DOM ....

If you hit F12 and open up the entry-image-container tag, hit refresh on the page you will notice that the entry-image-container is loaded through Opacity and seems to be causing a delay in loading (i'd have posted an image but StackOverflow says im not of higher enough rep yet)

Perhaps including a conditional statement for this tag would resolve the issue for you?

I hope this has helped in some way - Using Chrome on Mac OSX

Comment: entry-image-container was the problem DIV.  Changed the css and I'm good to go.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The header has a 44px padding (22px 0 44px).
For me (current stable FF, Win7) nothing is moving.

Comment: I can't see anything moving weirdly either (Chrome 17, OS X 10.7.3)